# Cacti extend snmp by a custom script

Tags: linux, bash, net-snmp, cacti

I have created a graph on Cacti about time to access to a specific page on our infrastructure with cacti and net-snmp.

I have extended the capability with adding two new lines in file /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf :

```
extend stat_page1 /usr/local/bin/cacti/access_page.sh context1
extend stat_page2 /usr/local/bin/cacti/access_page.sh context2
```

I have restarted the daemon snmpd to load this configuration.

The script called is describe below, with other value, because for some reason, i can show this.

```
#!/bin/bash

domain="mydomain"
cookie_name="myCookie"
token="myToken"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then

        if [ "$1" = "context1" ]
                then

                        target_url="https://${domain}/${1}/page1.html"
                        TIME=$(curl  -s -w "%{time_total}" -o /dev/null  --cookie \"${cookie_name}=${token}\" ${target_url})
        echo "$TIME"
        elif [ "$1" = "context2" ]
                then
                        target_url="https://${domain}/${1}/page2.html"
                        TIME=$(curl  -s -w "%{time_total}" -o /dev/null  --cookie \"${cookie_name}=${token}\" ${target_url})
        echo "$TIME"
        fi
```

If I launch the script manually i have this

```
$ /usr/local/bin/cacti/access_page.sh context2
0.061
$ /usr/local/bin/cacti/access_page.sh context1
0.041
```

When I launch the script with snmpget, I have this result:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c myCommunity localhost NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput2Table 
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."stat_page1".1 = STRING: 0.000
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."stat_page2".1 = STRING: 0.000
```

All time, I get **0.000** value by `snmp` command and manually a real value.

Could you help me about it?, please

Comment: You have not defined the `PATH` variable in your script. The value of `PATH` variable in your interactive session MAY BE different than the value when `snmpwalk` launches your script. Either check the `curl` command can be reached when the script is launched by `snmpwalk` or add the full path of `curl` executables.

Comment: Hi,<br> thanks for your reply. <br> I have tried to add in my script the complete path and I have the same result and I have test with adding an export of path as export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/:/bin/, but it the same :(

Comment: To debug your script, include debugging commands whose outputs are redirected to files, for instance, `echo curl -s -w "%{time_total}" -o /dev/null  --cookie \"${cookie_name}=${token}\" ${target_url} > /tmp/echo-curl.txt` and check the contents of the file `/tmp/echo-curl.txt`

Comment: Hi, I have done this test and when i call the script i have permission denied when I do this : line 34: /tmp/echo-curl: Permission denied, and I have done a script with just id to be sure that is launched with privilege user.

Comment: I have find the source of the problem, which is probably due to enforcing of SELinux

Answer (score 1):

Recently i had an issue with `snmp` and the execution script that call the `curl` command.

This post was the closest of the problem when i searched some solutions.

I found a solution without disabling SELinux.

I am a newbie in SELinux but i solved this issue with some SELinux configuration, that could interest someone in the future.

### Context :

- Centos 7
- Content of the configuration file for SNMP `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` :

---

```
#       sec.name    source      community
com2sec myuser      default     public
#       groupName   securityModel   securityName
group   mygroup     v2c     pad
#       name        incl/excl   subtree         mask(optional)
view    systemview  included    .1.3.6.1.4
view    systemview  included    .1.3.6.1.4.1
view    systemview  included    .1.3.6.1.4.1.1234
view    systemview  included    .1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.1
#       group   context sec.model   sec.level   prefix  read        write   notif
access  mygroup ""  any     noauth      exact   systemview  none    none
perl do "/appli/snmp_scripts/agent.pl"
```

---

- SNMAP agent agent.pl :

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use NetSNMP::agent (':all');
use NetSNMP::ASN qw(ASN_OCTET_STR ASN_INTEGER);

sub handler {
  my ($handler, $registration_info, $request_info, $requests) = @_;
  my $request;

  for($request = $requests; $request; $request = $request->next()) {
    my $oid = $request->getOID();
    if ($request_info->getMode() == MODE_GET) {
      if ($oid == new NetSNMP::OID(".1.3.6.1.4.1.1581.1.6.2.1.5")) {
    $request->setValue(ASN_OCTET_STR,`/path/to/myscript`);
      }
    }
  }
}

my $AGENT_OID = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.1234";
$agent->register("MYAGENT", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.1234",
                 \&handler);
```

---

### Solution:

When i looked for trace of the execution, with `sudo systemctl status snmpd`, some trace of curl were display :

```
snmpd: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:8081 Permission denied
```

However, the server was running well at this port and the script executed outside SNMP worked well.

SELinux errors have been generated in audit logs :

```
$> sudo grep snmp /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -w -a
type=AVC msg=audit(1528188940.802:2025): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=26809 comm="curl" dest=8081 scontext=system_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:transproxy_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
    Was caused by:
        Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

        You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

---

```
$> sudo grep snmp /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mysnmpmodule

******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i snmpdcanopensocket.pp
```

---

Follow the step told by audit2allow comm apply to SELinux the new created module for `snmp_t`. The `audit2allow -M` command generated two files snmpdcanopensocket.pp  snmpdcanopensocket.te in your current directory.
SELinux needs the .pp file to remap it's security rules.

```
$> semodule -i snmpdcanopensocket.pp
```

Restart the SNMP service with `sudo systemctl restart snmp`

Now the curl in the script executed by SNMP behaves well and does not quit with a (7) error code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this test and when i call the script i have permission denied when I do this : line 34: /tmp/echo-curl: Permission denied, and I have done a script with just id to be sure that is launched with privilege user.

I have find the source of the problem, which is probably due to enforcing of SELinux – user3249935